# 3 columns design: Third one with an image stretching to 100%

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm building a new website and I think I've made my designs a bit too complicated so now I'm struggling with code.

I'd like to have my website made of three columns, which will sit next to each other.

Column 1 will have `width:200px` and `height:100%` so it will fill the screen vertically, then next to it there will be a second column with `width:500px` and the same `height:100%`. And finally the last column will fill the rest of the screen, so it will be `width:100%` and `height:100%`, and in that column I would like to place an image which will stretch and fill that div.

Is that possible? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Edit your question to include it, and optionally also make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: If you found some way of expanding the height of image with the height its going to look pretty distorted. What are you trying to achieve with the image? If its a texture or graphic you could try making it a background image and repeating.

Comment: here is my design http://www.fsdegrees.com/subpage.jpg i think Jasper solution will work i will try that but image might get a bit restored so some jquery might be required

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a little CSS:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right">
        <img src="http://www.thegardenhelper.com/pixpg/graphics/sammy.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*You want to make sure the document is set to the fullscreen width*/
html, body {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
/*Set the container div to the full size of the document and set its position to something other than `static` so its children will take their position relatively from it*/
#container {
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    position   : relative;
    background : black;
}
/*absolutely position the left column to be 200px wide*/
#left {
    position : absolute;
    left     : 0px;
    top      : 0px;
    width    : 200px;
    height   : 100%;
}
/*absolutely position the middle column to be 500px wide and start 200px from the left*/
#middle {
    position   : absolute;
    left       : 200px;
    top        : 0px;
    width      : 500px;
    height     : 100%;
    background : blue;
}
/*absolutely position the right column to take the rest of the page starting from 700px from the left*/
#right {
    position   : absolute;
    left       : 700px;
    top        : 0px;
    right      : 0px;
    height     : 100%;
    background : red;
}
/*set the image to 100% height and width to fill its container (#right)*/
/*alternatively you can set the width of the image to `auto` so it will scale with the aspect ratio intact but still take-up 100% of the page's height*/
#right > img {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    border : none;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle of the above solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/7y9DZ/2/

Comment: Hi Jasper your solution worked fine but image got distorted so i used one of the Jquery plugin to overcome that but for some reasons plugin is not 100% working especially in IE browsers (nothing new here) have a look http://bonta.co.uk/test/test.html do you know any better solutions to that, many thanks

Comment: IF by distorted you mean the aspect ratio doesn't stay the same, just change either the `height` or `width` of the image to `auto`: `#right > img { width  : 100%; height : auto; border : none;}` and set the overflow of the `#right` div to `hidden` so it clips the image: `#right { position : absolute; left : 700px; top : 0px; right : 0px; height : 100%; background : red; overflow : hidden;}`. Here is a jsfiddle with the two suggested alterations: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/7y9DZ/3/